# row rank = column rank, confusion about wikipedia proof using linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

The fifth line: Now, each row of $A$ is given by a linear combination of the $r$ rows of $R$.**Therefore, the rows of $R$ form a spanning set of the row space of $A$**

I think the first half only implies that the row space of $A$ is a subspace of space which spanned by rows of $R$, but the second half means they are identical, why? Thanks for advance!

Comment: You are correct about your statement regarding the row space. "Therefore, the rows of $R$ form a spanning set of the row-space of $A$" is used to conclude that the row space of $A$ is a subset of the row space of $R$, which leads to their conclusion that "the row rank of $A$ cannot exceed $r$". That is, they conclude that the dimension of the row space of $A$ is less than or equal to $r$, which is the dimension of the row space of $R$. This result only becomes equality **after** the line "This result can be applied to any matrix, so apply the result to the transpose of $A$".

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks, and then I also find that $R$ is the matrix which rows are linear independent.